# Counting all file and folders including hidden in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I've got a program (function) like

```
countf()
{
    for f in "$1"/* "$1"/.[!.]*; do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; 
        then
            folders=$(($folders + 1))
            countf "$f"
        else
            files=$(($files + 1))
        fi
    done
}
```

It gives the correct value when the folder contains atleast 1 hidden file. However, it assumes "$1/.[!.]*" as a file and counts it when there's no hidden files.

This is my work around for the problem

```
countf()
{
    for f in "$1"/* "$1"/.[!.]*; do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; 
        then
            folders=$(($folders + 1))
            countf "$f"
        else
            # added if else
            if [ "$f" != "$1/.[!.]*" ]; then files=$(($files + 1)); fi
        fi
    done
}
```

I cannot use find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no hidden file, the pattern will be treated literally, and since it is not a directory, you assume it is a file. Simply verify that `$f` is a file, like you checked if it was a directory, before incrementing the file count.

```sh
countf()
{
    for f in "$1"/* "$1"/.[!.]*; do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; 
        then
            folders=$(($folders + 1))
            countf "$f"
        elif [ -f "$f" ]
        then
            files=$(($files + 1))
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count files:

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

To count directories

```
find . -type d | wc -l
```

`.` stands for the current directory.  Replace with appropriate path if looking at a different directory.

Comment: This will fail in the (admittedly rare) occasion when a file or directory name contains a newline.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use find

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to set `nullglob` to avoid counting this glob pattern:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

**TEST:** Doing this in an empty directory:

```
> echo ./.[!.]*
./.[!.]*

> shopt -s nullglob
> echo ./.[!.]*

>
```